# Incremental Game Time Format

Tags: code-golf, date

### Incremental Game Time Format

#### Goal

Incremental games often have a countdown timer expressing the days, hours, minutes and seconds until a task is complete.  Depending on the space available, they can be formatted as:

```
2d 13h
23h 59m 48s
14m
3h 0m 0s
```

The goal of this code golf is to write a function or program that performs this formatting.

#### Inputs

- The total number of seconds.
- The maximum number of segments to output.

#### Output

- Segments include:

  - **0w** weeks
  - **0d** days
  - **0h** hours
  - **0m** minutes
  - **0s** seconds
- Each segment is separated by a single space.
- Displayed segments must be contiguous.  For example, you will not show hours and seconds without showing minutes, even if there are zero minutes.
- Single-digit values do not have leading zeros, though a value of zero must be shown as `0`.
- Values are rounded down.
- The first segment displayed is the first non-zero value.

#### Test Cases

```
seconds  segments  output
     0      1      0s
   123      1      2m
   123      2      2m 3s
   123      3      2m 3s
 82815      3      23h 0m 15s
307891      2      3d 13h
307891      4      3d 13h 31m 31s
604800      1      1w
604800      6      1w 0d 0h 0m 0s
```

#### Winning

The lowest byte-count solution in one week will win "acceptance".

#### Edits

- Clarified which segment is first, as shown in examples.
- Added test case 4 as per request.

Comment: What is expected output for `307891    1`? `0w` or `1w`.

Comment: @jnovacho Wouldn't it be `3d`? *"The first segment displayed is the first non-zero value"*

Comment: @Luigi True. I've missed that.

Comment: Am I the only one thinking that this is a "could some one please write this code for me" question?

Comment: It's not every day a code golf task might actually be useful. I say go with it :D

Comment: @fho, if I wanted to write this function for production code, I would be writing it maintainable, not golfing it.  ;-P

Comment: @Hand-E-Food point taken ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## CJam (snapshot), <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```
q~"<<^X^G"{imd\}%W%"wdhms":s.+_{0=}#><S*
```

The above uses caret notation, since two of the characters are unprintable.

*Thanks to @Sp3000 for golfing off 2 bytes.*

#### Testing

The latest stable release (0.6.5) has a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/tickets/72/) that can cause `{}#` to return Integers instead of Longs. Quite paradoxically, this can be circumvented by casting to integer (`i`).

To run this with code with the online interpreter, click [this permalink](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%22%3C%3C%18%07%22%7Bimd%5C%7D%25W%25%22wdhms%22%3As.%2B_%7B0%3D%7D%23i%3E%3CS*&input=2%20307891) or copy the code from [this paste](http://pastebin.com/x5hQRGhD).

Alternatively, you can download and build the latest snapshot by executing the following commands:

```
hg clone http://hg.code.sf.net/p/cjam/code cjam-code
cd cjam-code/
ant
```

You can create the CJam file like this:

```
base64 -d > game-time.cjam <<< cX4iPDwYByJ7aW1kXH0lVyUid2RobXMiOnMuK197MD19Iz48Uyo=
```

#### How it works

```
q~        e# Read an evaluate the input.
"<<^X^G"  e# Push the string corresponding to the array [60 60 24 7
{         e# For each character:
  i       e#   Replace it by its code point.
  md      e#   Push divisor and residue of the division by that code point.
  \       e#   Swap their order.
}%
W%        e# Reverse the resulting array.
"wdhms":s e# Push ["w" "d" "h" "m" "s"].
.+        e# Perform vectorized concatenation.
_         e# Push a copy.
{0=}#     e# Find the index of the first pair with positive integer.
>         e# Remove the preceding pairs.
<         e# Truncate to the number of pairs specified in the input.
S*        e# Join, separating by spaces.
```

Answer (score 6):

## Java, <s>197</s> 191 bytes

```java
String p(int s,int m){String a[]={s%60+"s",(s/=60)%60+"m",(s/=60)%24+"h",(s/=24)%7+"d",(s/7)+"w"},b="",z="";for(s=5;s>0&&a[--s].charAt(0)=='0';);for(;s>=0&&--m>=0;z=" ")b+=z+a[s--];return b;}
```

I just noticed that Java supports declaration like `String a[]`. This allowed me to pull the declaration of `b` and `z` into the same line, which saved me from writing `String` again.

Comment: Like the `;z=" ")` - very clever.

Answer (score 5):

## C, <strike>134</strike> <strike>127</strike> <strike>110</strike> <strike>104</strike> 103 bytes

New Version:

```c
a,e=5;f(n,x){for(;e;n%=a)a=(int[]){1,60,3600,86400,604800}[--e],x>e?printf("%u%c ",n/a,"smhdw"[e]):0;}
```

Previous Version:

```c
#define p(a) x>--e?printf("%u%c ",n/a,"smhdw"[e]):0;n%=a;
e=5;f(n,x){p(604800)p(86400)p(3600)p(60)p(1)}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>39</s> 43 bytes

```
jd_>vz+V?u?GeGPG+m%~/QddCM"<<"Q)Q]0"smhdw
```

edit: +4 chars, because I forgot the `0s` test case.

This includes 2 unprintable chars. Get the actual code and try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jd_%3Evz%2BV%3Fu%3FGeGPG%2Bm%25~%2FQddCM%22%3C%3C%18%07%22Q%29Q]0%22smhdw&input=2%0A0&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
                                         z = 1st input line (segments, as string)
                                         Q = 2nd input line (time, as int)
                         "<<.."          string with 4 chars
                       CM                convert to ASCCI-values => [60,60,24,7]
                m                        map each d of ^ to:
                   /Qd                     Q / d 
                  ~                        update Q, but use the old value for
                 %  Q d                    Q mod d
                                         this gives [sec, min, hour, day]
               +               Q         add Q (week)
        u                       )        apply the following expression to G, 
                                         starting with G = [s,m,h,d,w], until
                                         G stops changing:
         ? eG                              if eG != 0:
          G                                  update G with G (stop changing)
                                           else:
             PG                              update G with G[-1]
                                         this gets rid of trailing zeros
      +V                         "smhdw  vectorized add with "smhdw"
   >vz                                   only use the last eval(z) items
  _                                      reverse order
jd                                       join by spaces and print
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2.7 - <s>181</s> <s>178</s> 174 bytes

My first attempt to golf something.

```python
def I(s,M):
 z=[0]*5;j=0
 for i in [604800,86400,3600,60,1]:z[j],s=s/i,s%i;j+=1
 l=[z.index(n)for n in z if n][0]
 return" ".join([str(i)+n for n,i in zip('wdhms',z)][l:l+M])
```

Comment: Great first attempt! Better than some of my sixth attempts... ;) You can cut off 3 bytes by changing `if n!=0` to just `if n`.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that 0 evaluates to False. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 158 bytes

I'm sure this could be shorter with a more clever approach, but this is what I have for now.

```matlab
(s,g)->(j=0;p=cell(5,1);for i=[604800,86400,3600,60,1] p[j+=1],s=s÷i,s%i end;z=findfirst(p);z>0?join([string(p[i],"wdhms"[i])for i=z:min(z+g-1,5)]," "):"0s")
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts two integers as input and returns a string. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=(s,g)->...`.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```matlab
function f(s, g)
    # Initialize an array and an index
    p = cell(5, 1)
    j = 0

    # Loop over the number of seconds in a week, day, hour,
    # minute, and second
    for i in [604800, 86400, 3600, 60, 1]
        # Set the jth element in p to be the quotient and s
        # to be the remainder of i into s
        p[j+=1], s = s ÷ i, s % i
    end

    # Get the index of the first nonzero value in p
    z = findfirst(p)

    if z > 0
        # We start the string at the first nonzero value
        # and continue until we hit the desired number of
        # units (z+g-1) or the maximum number of units (5),
        # whichever comes first. The appropriate unit is
        # appended to each value and the values are then
        # joined with a space.
        join([string(p[i], "wdhms"[i]) for i in z:min(z+g-1,5)], " ")
    else
        # If there are no nonzero values in p, we just
        # have 0 seconds
        "0s"
    end
end
```

Examples:

```matlab
julia> f(82815, 6)
"23h 0m 15s"

julia> f(604800, 4)
"1w 0d 0h 0m"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 367 bytes

```
^(\d+)/(_)^^(\1)
(_*) (\d)/\1!\2
_{60}/#
#{60}/@
@{24}/:
:{7}/;
(_+)/(^^\1)s
(#+)/(^^\1)m
(@+)/(^^\1)h
(:+)/(^^\1)d
(;+)/(^^\1)w
([a-z])/\1 
w ((\d+[^\dd])|!)/w 0d \1
d ((\d+[^\dh])|!)/d 0h \1
h ((\d+[^\dm])|!)/h 0m \1
(m|^) ?!/\1 0s!
!(\d+)/!(_)^^(\1)
#
+#(\d+)([a-z]) ?(.*)!(_*)/\1\2 #\3!\4@
#/
(@+)/ (_)^^((^^\1))
!(_+) \1(_*)/!\2
_+ _+/
+\d+[a-z] ?!_/!
 *!/
^$/0s
```

[Live demo and all test cases.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%5E(%5Cd%2B)%2F(_)%5E%5E(%5C1)%0A(_*)%20(%5Cd)%2F%5C1!%5C2%0A_%7B60%7D%2F%23%0A%23%7B60%7D%2F%40%0A%40%7B24%7D%2F%3A%0A%3A%7B7%7D%2F%3B%0A(_%2B)%2F(%5E%5E%5C1)s%0A(%23%2B)%2F(%5E%5E%5C1)m%0A(%40%2B)%2F(%5E%5E%5C1)h%0A(%3A%2B)%2F(%5E%5E%5C1)d%0A(%3B%2B)%2F(%5E%5E%5C1)w%0A(%5Ba-z%5D)%2F%5C1%20%0Aw%20((%5Cd%2B%5B%5E%5Cdd%5D)%7C!)%2Fw%200d%20%5C1%0Ad%20((%5Cd%2B%5B%5E%5Cdh%5D)%7C!)%2Fd%200h%20%5C1%0Ah%20((%5Cd%2B%5B%5E%5Cdm%5D)%7C!)%2Fh%200m%20%5C1%0A(m%7C%5E)%20%3F!%2F%5C1%200s!%0A!(%5Cd%2B)%2F!(_)%5E%5E(%5C1)%0A%23%0A%2B%23(%5Cd%2B)(%5Ba-z%5D)%20%3F(.*)!(_*)%2F%5C1%5C2%20%23%5C3!%5C4%40%0A%23%2F%0A(%40%2B)%2F%20(_)%5E%5E((%5E%5E%5C1))%0A!(_%2B)%20%5C1(_*)%2F!%5C2%0A_%2B%20_%2B%2F%0A%2B%5Cd%2B%5Ba-z%5D%20%3F!_%2F!%0A%20*!%2F%0A%5E%24%2F0s&input=0%201%0A123%201%0A123%202%0A123%203%0A82815%203%0A307891%202%0A307891%204%0A604800%201%0A604800%206)

Messy, messy, messy...

Takes about 3-7 seconds to execute the test cases on Chrome for Android. Do *not* use debug mode, which can freeze your browser in this case because of all the output that would be printed.

Comment: What's rs?-----

Comment: @Wideshanks I added a link in the title. It's a regex-based language-ish thing I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

### Scala, 147 bytes

```
def p(s:Int,i:Int)=List(s/604800+"w",s/86400%7+"d",s/3600%24+"h",s/60%60+"m",s%60+"s").dropWhile(k=>k.head=='0'&&k.tail!="s").take(i).mkString(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#, <strike>239 237 170</strike> 164 bytes

This is no where near as compact as other solutions, but I can't pose this challenge without having a stab at it myself.

This latest iteration was inspired by [ESC's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52796/4934).

Indented for clarity:

```
string G(int s,int n){
    int[]x={s%60,(s/=60)%60,(s/=60)%24,(s/=24)%7,s/7};
    for(s=5;x[--s]==0&s>0;);
    var o="";
    while(n-->0&s>=0)
        o+=" "+x[s]+"smhdw"[s--];
    return o.Trim();
}
```